# APNS Push notification received incorrect

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Our company has multiple apps, all with different app id's of course. We've seen issues lately that push notifications are sent to a device as being from app X while in reality it was sent for app Y

User opens app Y, our backend registers its device token. User uses the app a bit and exists
Same user now opens app X, backend registers this device too.

Now a push message is sent to app Y, the user receives this message but the device shows it as if it has been received by app X. When clicking on the notification app X opens.

note: all apps use separate databases

We have checked the .pem files we use (our backend to send notifications to apns is written in PHP) and those are just fine. The connection manager properly sends to APNS using the right certificate too.

What would be the issues of this problem and of course the solution?

Comment: When you say the PEM files are "fine" does this mean there are separate PEM files for each application? Meaning 1 production certificate PEM file for each app?

Comment: Yes, each app has its own unique PEM file. All made from their own respective unique p12 files obtained from the 3rd party that made the apps (we only did the backend).

Answer (score 3):

Did you remember to close the connection to the APNS server at the end of your .php scripts that communicate with APNS?

Just put this line at the end:

```
fclose($fp);
```

Where $fp is your connection declared earlier like so:

```
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

The reason you're getting this problem is likely because the connection from other apps hasn't closed. When they're left open, new notifications get sent from the last app that opened a connection to the server. My company had the same problem, and when we closed the connection at the end of all of our APNS scripts for our different apps, the problem went away.

Please let me know if this worked for you.